# dictionary implementation in Java

Tags: java

I use collection framework for it but If I want implement phone book in Java two person have same name but different mobile number we take name as a key but two person have same name then how to do in hashtable or hashmap can't take the same key but person have same name first person  name "saurabh" and second person name "saurabh"then

Hashtable or hashmap is option but it have unique Kay value

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit? Make some examples? Unfortunately I don't really get the problem nor the situation. Maybe also show some of your code.

Comment: Use [edit] option to clarify your question.

Comment: If I want implement phone book in Java two people have same name but different mobile number we take name as a key but two people have same name then how to do it we cannot take the same key but people have same name first people neme saurabh and second people name saurabh then

Comment: hashtable != hashmap

Comment: Hashtable or hashmap but it have unique key value

Comment: Use a unique value. Names are not unique. Or accumulate them in a container value. A `List` for example. `HashMap<String, List<...>>`. Then you can save multiple values for one key.

Comment: It is still very unclear what your question is. If two people have identical names you can't get a single phone number for this name. You will get a *collection* of phone numbers. So the value type of your map has to be a collection like a list.

Comment: So which collection framework or hashtable hashmap better for it

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Give us example of data you have/want to process and expected results. For now we know that there can be situation where two people have same name but different phone numbers. What is response you expect to get when user will ask using that shared (so **not unuque** as you claim) name? Should user get two phone numbers (here you should use collection as result)? Or should something else happened (what then)?

Comment: Anyway ["If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use HashMap in place of Hashtable"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

Comment: If I want add in hashtable 1)key as saurabh and phone number 5894570   2) key as saurabh again and phone number 488383   3)  key as rock and  phone number as 468848 I get problem in first two value how to store in hashtable but hashtable can't save unique key values

Answer (score 0):

> two people have same name but different mobile number we take name as a key but two people have same name then how to do it

Names should not be used as the unique identifier.

One solution is to check if the current name to be added already existed in the phonebook before you add the entry. If it is, append an incrementing numeric value behind:

```
For e.g.

Add "adam" --> "adam" added
Add "adam" --> "adam(1)" added
Add "adam" --> "adam(2)" added
```

Comment: So which collection framework or the hashtable hashmap use for it which is better

Comment: You can use any of it. The issues you are currently facing is a design issue. Data structure wise, you can use either. HashMap is fine. If you want it comes sorted, you can use TreeMap.